# Undefined mixin 'media-breakpoint-only'

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, css, compass-sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to start some bootstrap4/sass coding.

I thought I did everything required to configure my environment/project setup:

using

> ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i386-mingw32]

amongst installed gems (tried some bootstrap 3 before):

> autoprefixer-rails (6.3.6.2)
>   bootstrap (4.0.0.alpha4, 4.0.0.alpha3)
>   bootstrap-sass (3.3.7, 3.3.6)
>   breakpoint (2.7.0)
>   compass (1.0.3)
>   compass-core (1.0.3)
>   compass-import-once (1.0.5)
>   sass (3.4.22)
>   sass-globbing (1.1.5, 1.1.0.pre.0)
>   sassy-buttons (0.2.6)
>   sassy-maps (0.4.0)

in styles.scss:

> @import "compass/css3";
>   @import 'variables/*.*';
>   @import "bootstrap";

in config.rb:

> require 'compass/import-once/activate'
>   require 'bootstrap'
>   require 'sass-globbing'
>   require 'breakpoint'

but my compass is working and producing styles.css:

```
/* line 18, c:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha4/assets
/stylesheets/bootstrap/_normalize.scss */
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

only untill some bootstrap mixins are used:

```
Error: Undefined mixin 'media-breakpoint-only'.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have everything you need but the order is wrong. the mixin `media-breakpoint-only` (a bootstrap sass function/mixin) is required for compass(?) to be working. Therefor you must change the order. The order (I think) should be like this:

1. require breakpoint
2. require bootstrap
3. require compass

The same for the styles.scss, bootstrap should come before compass. If this didn't work try another order. Let me know.